# Angular 2 RC4 to RC5 - No provider for ViewContainerRef

Tags: angular

I have a big project written in RC4 and have some problems while updating it to RC5.

```
zone.js:484Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for ViewContainerRef! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: NoProviderError {message: "No provider for ViewContainerRef!", stack: "Error: DI Exception↵    at NoProviderError.BaseExc…ost:3000/vendor.js?3a298925c7ec72a2d72b:13238:19)", keys: Array[1], injectors: Array[1]} Error: DI Exception
    at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js?3a298925c7ec72a2d72b:4821:24)
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js?3a298925c7ec72a2d72b:6355:17)
    at new NoProviderError (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js?3a298925c7ec72a2d72b:6392:17)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js?3a298925c7ec72a2d72b:6255:20)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js?3a298925c7ec72a2d72b:6283:26)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js?3a298925c7ec72a2d72b:6246:26)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js?3a298925c7ec72a2d72b:6055:22)
    at NgModuleInjector.DynamicModuleInjector.createInternal (DynamicModule.ngfactory.js:295:87)
    at NgModuleInjector.create (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js?3a298925c7ec72a2d72b:13254:77)
    at NgModuleFactory.create (http://localhost:3000/vendor.js?3a298925c7ec72a2d72b:13238:19)consoleError @ zone.js:484_loop_1 @ zone.js:511drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:515
zone.js:486Error: Uncaught (in promise): No provider for ViewContainerRef!(…)
```

All I have done is upgrade the versions in package.json and then started the project.

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: Check official Angular 2 documentation for RC4 to RC5 Migration. Feel free to ask if something isn't clear to you. But, considering it is a big project, you will probably need some time to successfully finish migration to RC5. Therefore, I strongly advise you to read NgModule documentation as well to understand how NgModules work. You can find mentioned documentation here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

Comment: Solved by changing the skeleton of the application as instructed on that article

Answer (score -3):

Changed the appliation skeleton as per
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html

and it works